# VB.net mySQL How to use DateAdd in sql query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm getting an error when the form load and it said FUNCTION databasename.DateAdd does not exist

```
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "update pawn set status = 'Renewed', date_added = DateAdd(month,4,date_added), first_date = DateAdd(month,5,first_date), second_date = DateAdd(month,6,second_date), due_date = DateAdd(month,7,due_date)"
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
con.Close()
```

Comment: Check MySQL's  [Date_add()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used VB.NET's [DateAdd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx) inside the query which won't work for MySQL because MySQL doesn't has an inbuilt function like that

Syntax for MySQL *date add* function is [`DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

```
   cmd.CommandText = "update pawn set status = 'Renewed' " & _
                     ",date_added = DATE_ADD(date_added,INTERVAL 4 MONTH)" & _
                     ",first_date = DATE_ADD(first_date,INTERVAL 5 MONTH)" & _
                     ",second_date = DATE_ADD(second_date,INTERVAL 6 MONTH)" & _
                     ",due_date = DATE_ADD(due_date,INTERVAL 7 MONTH)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below-

```
ADDDATE(date_column, INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
ADDDATE(date_column, INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
ADDDATE(date_column, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```