# date add in sql query, vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I want to use the date add function in this sql query I have. I tried multiple ways of formatting it, but I can't get it to work. This is one of the ways I tried it: [VB.net mySQL How to use DateAdd in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262764/vb-net-mysql-how-to-use-dateadd-in-sql-query)

Below is the query I have.

```
sql.runquery("Select th.Thickness, odo.OptionCode
                        From FVMASTER..trackinghistory th
                        Join FVMASTER..OrderDetailOptions odo on odo.odKey=th.odKey
                        Join FVMASTER..MasterPartOptions mpo on mpo.Code=odo.OptionCode And mpo.[Group]=odo.optiongroup And mpo.QuestionKey='KGLASS' and OptionType=5
                        where th.DateTime >'"date_added = DATE_ADD(date_added,INTERVAL -4 DAY)")
```

This might also interest you. This is declared above the query.

```
 Dim dtimeStartDate As DateTime = GetWeekStartDate(tbWeek.Text, tbYear.Text)
 Dim dtimeEndDate As DateTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, dtimeStartDate)
```

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tagging the question with the database. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The <sql> tag is general ANSI SQL, but you're using the DATE_ADD functions, which is product specific.

Comment: You can't put a " (double quote) in the middle of a string without escaping it. A " indicates the end of the string. If you want this character as part of the string then use "". The compiler will then interpret this as a single " contained in the string.

Comment: In your previous question, you stated this is MS Sql Server. Joins normally link a primary key to a foreign key. You have put several And clauses on the second clause. These might belong in the where clause.

Comment: I don't understand why the 2 variables you declare at the end of your question have anything to do with the query.

Comment: If you are using Sql Server, there is no DATE_ADD function. This is a MySql (a different database) function. In Sql Server it is DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You absolutely must let us know what database you are using to get help.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146828/mysql-selecting-yesterdays-date) which provides direction, not a direct solution for the `where` condition using `subdate`